# how to create a search box for find pages of website in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, search

i want to create a search field for my website which search my  pages from website like if i search about us page i get about us page.so how i create that i create a search field in view

```
        <form action="#" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search here...">
        <button type="submit">
        </button>
        </form>
```

what should i write in controller. how can i do this ?????and how to use java script for search. ????

Comment: query db about your pages

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: i am thinking of create array of pages which contain page name and their link and search that array. its just an idea how to do this  ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how deep you want to search in your pages (just the title, or in the content too), you can store your pages in a table, with, title, content, keywords... and of course url. Then you perform a search in this table. You can search in javascript (then use ajax, example here : http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/live-search-using-jquery-ajax-php-codeigniter-and-mysql) or in php using a search controller.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot solve this problem using only JavaScript efficiently.

Either you create your own search engine in PHP, or you use a service like [SpinxSearch](https://github.com/sphinxsearch/sphinx) or [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/).

Basically, you have to create a button that creates a query, and then it displays a page with the results of that query.

Answer (score 0):

To me, your question is not too clear.

You will need php to a great deal for this. Javascript give you the response sent from the server.

From the bit of what i understood from your question: you can create a sitemap (which is a page that shows users how to navigate through your website). The sitemap would have a link of all the pages, well structured and arranged for the user to see.

Grace...